# How can I use mocks in a DoFn unittest?

Tags: mockito, google-cloud-dataflow

My DoFn has some external dependencies that I'd like to mock out in my unittest using [Mockito](http://mockito.org/). Normally I use [DoFnTester](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/java-sdk/JavaDoc/com/google/cloud/dataflow/sdk/transforms/DoFnTester) to unittest my DoFns.

Is it possible to verify expectations on a mock object when using [DoFnTester](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/java-sdk/JavaDoc/com/google/cloud/dataflow/sdk/transforms/DoFnTester)?

Answer (score 2):

The solution I came up with doesn't use DoFnTester but invokes the ProcessElement method directly.

Here's a snippet:

```
FileHelper fileHelper = mock(FileHelper.class);
when(fileHelper.createLocalTempDir())
  .thenReturn(new File("/tmp/someTempDIr"));

MyDoFn buildFn = new MyDoFn(fileHelper);
ProcessContext mockContext = mock(ProcessContext.class);
buildFn.processElement(mockContext);

verify(fileHelper).createLocalTempDir();
```

The problem I ran into trying to use DoFnTester was that DoFnTester serializes and deserializes the DoFn. As a result, the mock instance I was verifying in my test function was not the one used in the processElement function.